# Which social media platforms should writers use to build a readership?

Tags: publishing

As a writer of YA science fiction and fantasy action romance, using social media to connect to my audience, **which are the most important and most "converting" (i.e. turning visitors into readers) social media platforms today?**

Comment: Facebook and Twitter have the two largest userbases. Goodreads is great for readers, but I'm not sure if you can interact with them as an "author".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every author and book is different. I've sold about 50,000 books in 3 years, so I'm a solid mid-list author.

I use my blog, Facebook, and Twitter the most.

Facebook is where I tend to get the most intimate engagement. I'll throw out plot questions or title brainstorming for my work-in-progress, and fans and friends and family will chime in with ideas. Lots of fun.

Twitter is where I tend to announce stuff that gets coverage to the broader world. I have a modest number of followers, but some of my followers have tens of thousands or hundreds of thousands of followers, so when they retweet, it gets a very big audience. This helps me get exposure to new people.

My blog is ultimately where I'm going to send people to find out about new books, write longer articles, find my entire list of books in order, and so forth. I consider that the most essential aspect of my online presence.

And lastly I have a mailing list, with signup through my blog. I only email out to that list once per month, but it has a very high level of response from fans. (I use mailchimp to maintain the list.)

In order of priority:

1. blog
2. mailing list
3. twitter
4. facebook

I'm also on Google+ but I use it the least.

Answer (score 2):

**[GOOGLE+](https://plus.google.com/).**

[image]

If you're targeting a specific niche I recommend [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/), just go to the forums of the authors/genre that inspired you and post your work there. Same for Facebook and Google+ (post on their respective pages/communities).

Answer (score 2):

Wattpad is a really good place to start. Almost everyone there is an aspiring writer and hence encourage other writers immensely. You can update status and post messages to your audience. There are many clubs within Wattpad to promote your works. https://www.wattpad.com